# How to fix prysm.sh beacon-chain stopped at 99% progress?

Tags: merge, beacon, chain, go-ethereum

geth stopped working after the merge, when I fix it by beacon-chain, beacon stopped progress at 99%.

command:

`prysm.sh beacon-chain --execution-endpoint=http://localhost:8551 --datadir=/disk1/prysm/.eth2`

logs:

`[2022-09-20 13:05:11]  INFO initial-sync: Processing block batch of size 63 starting from  0x35967a9b... 4700032/4737924 - estimated time remaining 22m9s blocksPerSecond=28.5 peers=47 [2022-09-20 13:05:11]  WARN initial-sync: Skip processing batched blocks error=beacon node doesn't have a parent in db with root: 0x97b0b7b53582569689c52dbee87990ea2d7a94b17ee823e704c99d07e81b5376 (in processBatchedBlocks, slot=4700032) [2022-09-20 13:05:11]  INFO initial-sync: Processing block batch of size 63 starting from  0x063c579d... 4700096/4737924 - estimated time remaining 19m55s blocksPerSecond=31.6 peers=47 [2022-09-20 13:05:11]  WARN initial-sync: Skip processing batched blocks error=beacon node doesn't have a parent in db with root: 0x91593f4ce1da4260a4475807af54ada66481b2e5529859fbcdd636c59966ac5d (in processBatchedBlocks, slot=4700096) [2022-09-20 13:05:11]  INFO initial-sync: Processing block batch of size 62 starting from  0xe5a59df5... 4700160/4737924 - estimated time remaining 18m6s blocksPerSecond=34.8 peers=47 [2022-09-20 13:05:11]  WARN initial-sync: Skip processing batched blocks error=beacon node doesn't have a parent in db with root: 0x099ce628bdb98cd34673e06f779a695a9fa903472f95f778a823c4b271296669 (in processBatchedBlocks, slot=4700160) [2022-09-20 13:05:11]  INFO initial-sync: Processing block batch of size 64 starting from  0xf0b0a565... 4700224/4737924 - estimated time remaining 16m33s blocksPerSecond=38.0 peers=47 [2022-09-20 13:05:11]  WARN initial-sync: Skip processing batched blocks error=beacon node doesn't have a parent in db with root: 0x6a644e5ce7eb9063ac0334eb070469ffe1babef71b42fc295a0098410c8509ff (in processBatchedBlocks, slot=4700224) [2022-09-20 13:05:11]  INFO initial-sync: Processing block batch of size 64 starting from  0x4aef416e... 4700288/4737924 - estimated time remaining 15m14s blocksPerSecond=41.1 peers=47 [2022-09-20 13:05:11]  WARN initial-sync: Skip processing batched blocks error=beacon node doesn't have a parent in db with root: 0xa165b5186776ed6adbeffbe7f9861a25cfe9e9a79b79fbf63c44f0f3f0fd2433 (in processBatchedBlocks, slot=4700288) [2022-09-20 13:05:11]  INFO initial-sync: Processing block batch of size 64 starting from  0xe2ad65e3... 4700352/4737924 - estimated time remaining 14m7s blocksPerSecond=44.4 peers=47 [2022-09-20 13:05:11]  WARN initial-sync: Skip processing batched blocks error=beacon node doesn't have a parent in db with root: 0x0d5b8ab2983591a9dd27b6b6b99540f75de7a6b7f88dfe6dd83ac5e8316b0d79 (in processBatchedBlocks, slot=4700352) [2022-09-20 13:05:11]  INFO initial-sync: Processing block batch of size 63 starting from  0xe08fde61... 4700416/4737924 - estimated time remaining 13m9s blocksPerSecond=47.5 peers=47 [2022-09-20 13:05:11]  WARN initial-sync: Skip processing batched blocks error=beacon node doesn't have a parent in db with root: 0xb493b115a9e7dadff196d1fd9092c477b3503a148983a6cd37111a00ba526862 (in processBatchedBlocks, slot=4700416)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting same error, you can check your GETH execution node, I think it stuck because of the GETH error

```
WARN [09-21|18:45:48.100] Ignoring already known beacon payload    number=15,580,285 hash=d2b656..2c59c3 age=3h23m49s
```

My beacon-chain got these error/warning

```
[2022-09-21 18:48:26]  WARN powchain: Execution client is not syncing
[2022-09-21 18:48:37]  WARN initial-sync: Skip processing batched blocks error=beacon node doesn't have a parent in db with root: 0x43b75c52f29244ca3caee03c5d3dbc52ac19e12d1fd8d2ae3e28c358719cb028 (in processBatchedBlocks, slot=4743744)
```

my `eth.blockNumber` is always **15,580,285**

Comment: I resynced it.it's ok now.

Comment: What exactly did you do to resync prysm?